# Assigning the splitAt n list to pair(x,y) in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a statement `[splitAt n list | n <- [1..((length list)-1)]`  which when runs on [1,2,3,4], gives `[([1],[2,3,4]),([1,2],[3,4]),([1,2,3],[4])]`
. I want to assign each pair to variables x and y

example:

```
x=[1]
y=[2,3,4]
x=[1,2]
y=[3,4] 
etc
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a pattern match (in this case on the pair returned by `splitAt`) inside a `let` in a list comprehension, so you can do

```
[ doSomethingWith x y | n <- [1..((length list)-1), let (x, y) = splitAt n list ]
```